# The exact definition of an in built Tactic (case, destruct, inversion etc.) in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

How can one see the exact implementation of an in-built tactic in Coq ?  More specifically is there an alternative to `Print Ltac <user-defined-tactics>` which works for locating the exact definition of in-built Tactics in Coq ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no alternative to `Print Ltac`.  In part, this is because the built-in tactics are implemented in OCaml, and the parts they are made of aren't always expressible in terms of more primitive tactics in Ltac (and almost never would such a translation be exact).  The only way I know to find the definitions is to go source-diving.  If you search for, e.g., `"destruct"`, you will find in [`plugins/ltac/g_tactic.ml4`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/a960c4db9ae93a6445f9db620f96f62b397ba8b5/plugins/ltac/g_tactic.ml4#L617-L618) the lines

```
  | IDENT "destruct"; icl = induction_clause_list ->
  TacAtom (Loc.tag ~loc:!@loc @@ TacInductionDestruct(false,false,icl))
```

which says that `destruct` gets parsed as the atomic tactic node `TacInductionDestruct`.  Searching for `TacInductionDestruct` gives an implementation in [`plugins/ltac/tacinterp.ml`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/2a25e1a56460556f8b8dcef2a70cd0d2b9422383/plugins/ltac/tacinterp.ml#L1774-L1801):

```
  (* Derived basic tactics *)
  | TacInductionDestruct (isrec,ev,(l,el)) ->
      (* spiwack: some unknown part of destruct needs the goal to be
         prenormalised. *)
      Proofview.Goal.nf_enter begin fun gl ->
        let env = Proofview.Goal.env gl in
        let sigma = project gl in
        let sigma,l =
          List.fold_left_map begin fun sigma (c,(ipato,ipats),cls) ->
            (* TODO: move sigma as a side-effect *)
             (* spiwack: the [*p] variants are for printing *)
            let cp = c in
            let c = interp_destruction_arg ist gl c in
            let ipato = interp_intro_pattern_naming_option ist env sigma ipato in
            let ipatsp = ipats in
            let sigma,ipats = interp_or_and_intro_pattern_option ist env sigma ipats in
            let cls = Option.map (interp_clause ist env sigma) cls in
            sigma,((c,(ipato,ipats),cls),(cp,(ipato,ipatsp),cls))
          end sigma l
        in
        let l,lp = List.split l in
        let sigma,el =
          Option.fold_left_map (interp_open_constr_with_bindings ist env) sigma el in
        Tacticals.New.tclTHEN (Proofview.Unsafe.tclEVARS sigma)
        (name_atomic ~env
          (TacInductionDestruct(isrec,ev,(lp,el)))
            (Tactics.induction_destruct isrec ev (l,el)))
      end
```

You can find the implementation of `Tactics.induction_destruct` in `tactics/tactics.ml`.

---

Most primitive tactics start in one of two ways: either there is an entry in `g_tactic.ml4` which says how to parse that tactic as an atomic tactic node, or there is a `TACTIC EXTEND` somewhere, e.g., for `revert`, we have in [`plugins/ltac/coretactics.ml4`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/e273ff57ef82e81ab6b6309584a7d496ae4659c1/plugins/ltac/coretactics.ml4#L238-L240)

```
TACTIC EXTEND revert
  [ "revert" ne_hyp_list(hl) ] -> [ Tactics.revert hl ]
END
```

If the definition is as a node in the Ltac AST, then the place to look is `tacinterp.ml`, which describes how to interpret those tactics.  Either way, you can continue chasing down OCaml definitions to see how tactics are implemented.